# Shift a decimal by 9 bits with awk (can't use gawk lshift)

Tags: bash, awk, hex, printf, shift

I need to left shift by 9bits a decimal number and print result in hexadecimal.

Here an example:

```
# Desired result:
perl -e "printf('%x', (99 << 9))"; echo;
c600

# Use case:
awk 'BEGIN{ d=99; printf("Decimal: %d, Hexadecimal: %x\n", d, d }'
Decimal: 99, Hexadecimal: 63 # Must be left shift by 9 (c600)
```

Can you give me a way to reproduce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ d=99; x=d*2^9; printf("Decimal: %d, Hexadecimal: %x\n", d, x )}'
Decimal: 99, Hexadecimal: c600
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless we have limited precision, left-shifting by 9 is the same as multiplying by 2^9=512:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ d=99; printf("Decimal: %d, Hexadecimal: %x\n", 512*d, 512*d) }'
Decimal: 50688, Hexadecimal: c600
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of awk, you can do this in bash itself using `printf`:

```
printf "%x\n" $((99 << 9))
c600
```

If you have to use awk (gnu) then use `lshift` function:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "%x\n", lshift(99, 9)}'
c600
```

Comment: using awk its mandatory for me, and for lshift: awk: line 2: function lshift never defined
But thank you for help

Comment: `lshift` is available with gnu awk not with older awk

Comment: you certainly have a /etc/default/ symbolic link from awk to gawk ^^ @anubhava

Comment: No I don't. I use OSX and keep BSD awk separately from `gawk` (installed via `home brew`)